# How to migrate from DotnetNuke to Drupal?

Tags: migrations

Currently we have DotNetNuke (= DNN) websites. We are planning to move the DNN websites into the Drupal platform.

My questions: how do I migrate the DNN content and users tables into the Drupal Mysql tables?

I have tried with Drupal Migrating Handbooks, but no luck.

Comment: Did migrate module worked for you? Could you migrate from DNN to Drupal? I am having the same situation and would like to know your experience

Answer (score 5):

There is a very good module to assist migration from other CMSs to Drupal called the [Migrate](http://drupal.org/project/migrate) module.

> The migrate module provides a flexible framework for migrating content into Drupal from other sources (e.g., when converting a web site from another CMS to Drupal). Out-of-the-box, support for creating core Drupal objects such as nodes, users, files, terms, and comments are included - it can easily be extended for migrating other kinds of content. Content is imported and rolled back using a bundled web interface (Migrate UI module) or included [Drush](http://drupal.org/project/drush) commands ([strongly recommended](http://drupal.org/node/1806824)).

Link : [Documentation](http://drupal.org/node/415260).

Comment: Migrate module is great. It takes a little while to learn how it all works but once you get there it is great.

Comment: @user16443 You're welcome. Don't forget to mark the solution as accepted in order to remove this question from the unanswered questions' list.